# Почему не соблюдаются пропорции объекта из Blender'a в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, blender

Есть объект в Блендере у которого при переносе в Unity не совпадает одна деталь.

В Blender:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Unity:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блендер файл: [тыц](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pieh4liszs7l2vv/ResultPost.blend?dl=0).

Comment: это текстура или замоделено так??

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это замоделено так и к вопросу прикреплён блендер файл.

Comment: я видел файл, но у меня на телефоне нет блендера. масштаб везде единица? и в юнити и в блендере? на всех мешах?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в блендере не везде единица. В юнити всё к 1:1:1

Comment: боюсь что проблема где-то около scale..., проверьте на простой модели, (я с таким сталкивался, когда получал модельки от разных дизайнеров и пытался их совмещать), нет уверенности что юнити правильно пересчитывает вершины при импорте, эот надо дебажить, но мне было лень, решалось приведением всех scale к 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно применить масштаб ко всем частям модели (*которые, кстати, все разные*).

В режиме объекта выделите каждую часть отдельно и нажмите *«**Ctrl + A**»* и примените масштаб(***Scale***). Должно сработать и приравнять все части модели/модель к масштабу **1:1:1**.

Comment: отлично что все получилось

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Каждый день узнаешь-решаешь проблему нового бага)